# Custom Reset Email Page in Angular with Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a custom reset password page for my angular and firebase project. I have set the customized URL to localhost/resetpassword page while testing the page. But I am not able to reset password successfully.

I am using ActivatedRoute to read the param values of mode, oobCode, continueUrl etc. Then I use confirmPassword with the auth object to get email and then confirm reset to set the password. Here is the TS code for my reset password component. I have a bunch of console.logs to get the issue. Here is the code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/forms';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reset-password-page',
  templateUrl: './reset-password-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reset-password-page.component.css']
})
export class ResetPasswordPageComponent implements OnInit {
  newPassword: string;
  mode: string;
  actionCode: string;
  continueUrl: string;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('In reset password');
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.mode = params['mode'];
      this.actionCode = params['oobCode'];
      this.continueUrl = params['continueUrl'];
      console.log(this.mode);
      console.log(this.actionCode);
      console.log(this.continueUrl);

    });

  }

  resetPassword(form: NgForm) {
    var password_attempt1 = form.value.password_first_time;
    var password_attempt2 = form.value.password_second_time;
    console.log(password_attempt1);
    console.log(password_attempt2)

    if(password_attempt1 === password_attempt2) {
      console.log('Passed password check');
      this.getAllParameters(this.mode, this.actionCode, this.continueUrl);

    } else {
      console.log('PASSWORDS DO NOT MATCH');
      this.router.navigate(['/resetpassword']);
    }

  }

  getAllParameters(mode, actionCode, continueUrl) {

    var auth = firebase.auth();
    console.log(auth);

    switch (mode) {
      case 'resetPassword':
        // Display reset password handler and UI.
        this.handleResetPassword(auth, actionCode, continueUrl);
        break;
      default:
      // Error: invalid mode.

    }
  }

  handleResetPassword(auth, actionCode, continueUrl) {
    console.log('In handle reset password');
    var accountEmail;
    auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(function (email) {
      accountEmail = email;

      auth.confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, this.newPassword).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Password Reset');
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('ERROR IN PASSWORD RESET');
      });

    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('INVALID OR EXPIRED ACTION CODE');
    })

  }

}
```

I expect password to reset and user is redirected to login page.

Comment: are you getting any errors from the API?

Comment: I am not getting errors. When I visit the page locally, I am able to retrieve the parameters using ActivatedRoute. However, when I push the code live, I am unable to retrieve those parameters and hence, unable to make a call to confirmPassword.

Comment: I am getting INVALID OR EXPIRED ACTION CODE when auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode) is getting called.

I don't understand because it is a fresh token, how can it be invalid.

Comment: Note: auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode) is throwing error. INVALID OR EXPIRED ACTION CODE is a custom message in catch.